# How can I catch tap on MapView and then pass it to default gesture recognizers?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

Here is what I want - user taps on the map, my code gets executed and then system code is executed (if user clicked on annotation callout is presented etc...).

I added simple tap recognizer to map view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapViewTapped:)];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[tapGestureRecognizer release];
```

Inside mapViewTapped my code gets executed. Now I want to notify system code of tap (for example to show callout). How do I do that? How to pass event that I intercepted?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way is to implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` and return `YES` in it:

```
//add <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to .h to avoid compiler warning

//add this where you create tapGestureRecognizer...
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Now your `mapViewTapped:` will get called and then the map view's recognizer will call its method.  If the tap was on an annotation view, the map view will show its callout (and the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method will get called if you've implemented it).

Another way, if you need more control, then instead of doing the above, in your `mapViewTapped:` you can check if the tap was on an annotation view and then manually select the annotation which will then show its callout (and call the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method):

```
-(void)mapViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tgr
{
    CGPoint p = [tgr locationInView:mapView];

    UIView *v = [mapView hitTest:p withEvent:nil];

    id<MKAnnotation> ann = nil;

    if ([v isKindOfClass:[MKAnnotationView class]])
    {
        //annotation view was tapped, select it...
        ann = ((MKAnnotationView *)v).annotation;
        [mapView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        //annotation view was not tapped, deselect if some ann is selected...
        if (mapView.selectedAnnotations.count != 0)
        {
            ann = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
            [mapView deselectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was not only useful, but very detailed

Comment: Many thanks, your second suggestion was exactly what I was after!

Comment: That is a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Second option for Swift enjoyers:

```swift
@objc private func mapViewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = sender.location(in: mapView)
    if let view = mapView.hitTest(point, with: nil) as? MKAnnotationView {
        if let annotation = view.annotation {
            mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        let selected = mapView.selectedAnnotations
        if selected.count != 0 {
            mapView.deselectAnnotation(selected[0], animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```