# How to add touch gesture to map but ignore touches on pins and annotations?

Tags: ios, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer, geometry

I have a mapview that uses `MKCircle`s to display radius information for certain user actions.

What I want to do, is allow the user to dismiss the `MKCircle` when they touch the map. However, I would like the `MKCircle` to NOT dismiss should the user touch any of the other pins or the `MKCircle` itself.

Any ideas?

Here is my current code, which dismisses the `MKCircle` when any part of the map is touched:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(deactivateAllRadars)];
[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[_mapView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `deactivateAllRadars` method, you can use `hitTest:withEvent:` to tell whether an `MKAnnotationView` has been tapped or not.

An example of this is shown in [How can I catch tap on MapView and then pass it to default gesture recognizers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700413/how-can-i-catch-tap-on-mapview-and-then-pass-it-to-default-gesture-recognizers) (it's the second code sample).

This will let you avoid removing the circle if an *annotation* has been tapped.

If an annotation has not been tapped, you can then check if an `MKCircle` was tapped by getting the coordinates of the touch (see [How to capture Tap gesture on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317810/how-to-capture-tap-gesture-on-mkmapview) for an example) and seeing if the distance from the touch to the circle's center is greater than its radius.

Note that the `deactivateAllRadars` should be changed to `deactivateAllRadars:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tgr` because it will need information from the associated gesture recognizer.  Also be sure to add a colon at the end of the method's selector where you alloc+init `tap`.

For example:

```
-(void)deactivateAllRadars:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tgr
{
    CGPoint p = [tgr locationInView:mapView];

    UIView *v = [mapView hitTest:p withEvent:nil];

    id<MKAnnotation> ann = nil;

    if ([v isKindOfClass:[MKAnnotationView class]])
    {
        //annotation view was tapped, select it...
        ann = ((MKAnnotationView *)v).annotation;
        [mapView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        //annotation view was not tapped, deselect if some ann is selected...
        if (mapView.selectedAnnotations.count != 0)
        {
            ann = [mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
            [mapView deselectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
        }


        //remove circle overlay if it was not tapped...        
        if (mapView.overlays.count > 0)
        {
            CGPoint touchPoint = [tgr locationInView:mapView];

            CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate 
              = [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

            CLLocation *touchLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] 
              initWithLatitude:touchMapCoordinate.latitude 
              longitude:touchMapCoordinate.longitude];

            CLLocation *circleLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] 
              initWithLatitude:circleCenterLatitude 
              longitude:circleCenterLongitude];

            CLLocationDistance distFromCircleCenter 
              = [touchLocation distanceFromLocation:circleLocation];

            if (distFromCircleCenter > circleRadius)
            {
                //tap was outside the circle, call removeOverlay...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work on iOS 7, an MKNewAnnotationContainerView is returned in the hit test. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz, MKNewAnnotationContainerView (private class) is what's returned when you tap on the map area which this particular code _doesn't care about_.  When you tap on an annotation, iOS 7 still returns MKAnnotationView (documented class) which is what the code _is checking for_.  If still an issue, please start a new Question with details.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't much clear, what I meant was that when you tap an annotation, it doesn't return an MKAnnotationView, it returns the MKNewAnnotationContainerView, same as when you tap the map area.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz, I am not able to duplicate that unfortunately.  Please post a new Question with details including the viewForAnnotation and gesture recognizer methods.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't much clear, what I meant was that when you tap an annotation, it doesn't return an MKAnnotationView, it returns the MKNewAnnotationContainerView, same as when you tap the map area.

I just tested it and what you said is true if you use the default MKPinAnnotationView, but if you return a custom annotation view in the
mapView:viewForAnnotation: delegate method, it aways returns the MKNewAnnotationContainerView.

Comment: I'm sorry to waste your time, just figured it out that it was my fault, I was overriding the hitTest method of my custom pin =)

Comment: There is one more problem though, when I tap 5 points away from the pin, the MKNewAnnotationContainerView is returned, but the pin is selected.

Answer (score 3):

This is my **Swift 2.1** compatible version:

```
func didTapOnMap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = recognizer.locationInView(self)
    if let subview = self.hitTest(tapLocation, withEvent: nil) {
        if subview.isKindOfClass(NSClassFromString("MKNewAnnotationContainerView")!) {
            print("Tapped out")
        }
    }
}
```

*MKNewAnnotationContainerView* is a private inner class, so you **cannot compare directly** like:

```
if subview is MKNewAnnotationContainerView {
}
```

Comment: Im way late to this, but when you say "private inner class", does this literally just mean that this is a private class that is inside of another class (perhaps MKAnnotationView)?

Comment: You're right, "inner" is misleading: I don't know where exactly MKNewAnnotationContainerView is defined, but it's private for sure. If you find any documentation, please feel free to update answer!

Comment: NSClassFromString("MKNewAnnotationContainerView") returns nil in Swift 4.2. Using NSClassFromString("MKAnnotationContainerView") fixed the issue.